# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter will not update or retrieve information

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm working to update the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and having a bit of trouble. I've tried quite a bit to the point where I'm at a loss. The following is my code:

```
    self.audioPlayer.allowsAirPlay = NO;

    Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

    if (playingInfoCenter) {

        NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArt = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"series_placeholder"]];

        [songInfo setObject:thePodcast.title forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:thePodcast.author forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
        [songInfo setObject:@"NCC" forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:albumArt forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];


    }
```

This isn't working, I've also tried:

```
   [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nil];
```

In an attempt to get it to remove the existing information from the iPod app (or whatever may have info there). In addition, just to see if I could find out the problem, I've tried retrieving the current information on app launch:

```
  NSDictionary *info = [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] nowPlayingInfo];
  NSString *title = [info valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
  NSString *author = [info valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

  NSLog(@"Currently playing: %@ // %@", title, author);
```

and I get `Currently playing: (null) // (null)`

I've researched this quite a bit and the following articles explain it pretty thoroughly, however, I am still unable to get this working properly. Am I missing something? Would there be anything interfering with this? Is this a service something my app needs to register to access (didn't see this in any docs)?

[Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Change lock screen background audio controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600592/change-lock-screen-background-audio-controls-text)

[Now playing info ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808031/mpnowplayinginfocenter-nowplayinginfo-ignored-for-avplayer-audio-via-airplay)

Comment: Is media playing when this code executes?

Comment: I've tried with audio playing (via MPMoviePlayer) and without with the same results

Comment: print [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] using nslog. In documentation they say : The default now playing info center holds now-playing information for the app that is designated as the receiver for remote-control events. Are you playing media on some remote device? make sure media is playing on some remote device. Because docs says : Remote-control events let users control application multimedia through the system transport controls or through an external accessory.

Comment: When I print MPNowPlayingInfoCenter I get: 
<MPNowPlayingInfoCenter: 0x2857c0>

Comment: I'm not playing to a remote device or accessory... my understanding is that you can update this information (as displayed on the lock screen) simply by playing audio on the device but that it can also be used for remote devices...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, I was not prompting my app to receive remote control events, simply adding this line fixed the problem:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Comment: I face a similar issue. Even though I implement all the above methods, i am not receiving control events. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973602/unable-to-receive-remotecontrolreceivedwithevent-objective-c-ios

Comment: Also, make sure you call `UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` _after_ you've setup the audio session. The following worked for me:

```swift
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the code below and it always works. I'm also using `MPMoviePlayer` like you. Have you checked whether `NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter")` ever actually returns `YES`? Have you set you app play audio in background key in your plist?

```
- (void) loadMPInformation
{
    NSDictionary *mpInfo;

    if([savedTrack.belongingAlbum.hasAlbumArt boolValue] == NO){
        mpInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:savedTrack.belongingAlbum.album, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle, 
                  savedTrack.belongingArtist.artist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, savedTrack.name, MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, nil];   
    } else {
        UIImage *artImage = [UIImage imageWithData:savedTrack.belongingAlbum.art];
        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:artImage];
        mpInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:savedTrack.belongingAlbum.album, MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle, 
                  savedTrack.belongingArtist.artist, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist, savedTrack.name, MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, artwork, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork, nil];
    }
    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = mpInfo;

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that it returns YES, I've also set that the app play audio in the plist...

Comment: Wait. Have you tried this on a device or on the simulator? Cause it never works in the simulator I've noticed.

Comment: I've only been trying it on the device... do you have to register to receive notification from the play/pause button?

Comment: I did. But I don't remember it being necessary--good thing to try though. Also, I remember `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` being pretty picky that no strings you send it are nil, be sure to test that too.

Comment: Yeah, none of the strings are nil

Comment: Also, have your thrown in: `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];`

Comment: yeah, and I've got error checking on that just in case and the session is being set properly

Comment: All I can say is register to receive notifications--might be required on your platform. Otherwise I dunno, the code should work. Is this iPhone?