# Media Info displayed in simulator but doesn't display on real device

Tags: swift, media-player, avfoundation

I have tried this code to show media info:

```
import MediaPlayer

let audioInfo = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()
audioInfo.nowPlayingInfo = [ MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Miley_Cyrus_", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:"artistName"]
```

This is working fine on simulator as shown into image:

[image]

But this is not working correctly on real Device:

[image]

There is no media info displayed in real device as displayed into simulator. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution for it

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

This is working fine.

Reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522591/mpnowplayinginfocenter-defaultcenter-will-not-update-or-retrieve-information).